Issue with \ccases of mtpro2 and mleftright package
In my preamble, I am using the mleftright package with the \mleftright macro:
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% no extra spacing around \left...\right constructs
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{mleftright}
\mleftright

This is to avoid extra spacing on the left and right when using \left( ... \right). I understand that the correct approach would be to use \big, \Big, \bigg, or \Bigg, but I don’t understand the reason using \ccases changes the styling of the curly braces.

With \mleftright:

\documentclass[10pt]{article}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
%   FONTS
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\let\Bbbk\relax
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2} 
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
% no extra spacing around \left...\right constructs
%-------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{mleftright}
\mleftright

\begin{document}
\[
\ccases{
\begin{aligned}
x&=x'+vt\\
y&=y'\\
z&=z'\\
t&=t'
\end{aligned}
}
\]
\end{document}



Without \mleftright (correct output):


PS: the macro \mleftright provides to have the right spaces into \left( and \right) in all document.

can you reproduce w/o mtpro. (I guess I'm not the only one doesn't have it.)

Can you skip running  \mleftright and write \mleft and \mright where needed?

@cfr - I believe the \ccases — “curly [curvy?] cases” — macro is specific to the mtpro2 package.

@Mico Yes, of course. But I think that in my long code of my book, I have severals \left( ... \right). I should change every \left( ... \right) in \mleft and \mright.

I can’t think of a downside of changing all instances of \left and \right to \mleft and \mright.

@Mico I will follow your advice :-)

Incidentally, you should load mathtools before, not after, newtxtext.
